# Script in Laravel Splade onchange

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I want some inputs to update when I click a checkbox.

As the most basic test to see if the script is running, I'm just making an alert when the checkbox is ticked.

But its not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
   <x-splade-form :default="[
        'allocated' => 0,
        'amount' => 100,
        'allocateme' => 0,
    ]">

        <x-splade-input label="Amount" name="amount" v-model="form.amount" />
        <x-splade-input label="Allocated" name="allocated" v-model="form.allocated" />
        <x-splade-input disabled label="Total" name="total" />
        <x-splade-checkbox @change="shout" label="Allocate this amount" name="allocateme" v-model="form.allocateme" value="1" />

    </x-splade-form>

    <x-splade-script>
        function shout() {
        alert('Checkbox was checked');
        }
    </x-splade-script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is used for vanilla j.s. if you want to use the vuejs then you've to create a custom component ex: renderless component

Answer (score 0):

In your Laravel Blade file, you can define a function within a `<x-splade-script>` tag and call it when the checkbox changes. Here's how you can do it:

```html
<x-splade-form :default="[
    'allocated' => 0,
    'amount' => 100,
    'allocateme' => 0,
]">

    <x-splade-input label="Amount" name="amount" v-model="form.amount" />
    <x-splade-input label="Allocated" name="allocated" v-model="form.allocated" />
    <x-splade-input disabled label="Total" name="total" />
    <x-splade-checkbox @change="$splade.shout" label="Allocate this amount" name="allocateme" v-model="form.allocateme" value="1" />

</x-splade-form>

<x-splade-script>
    $splade.shout = function() {
       const form = $parent.$all;
       alert(form.allocateme);
    }
</x-splade-script>
```

In this example, the `$splade.shout` function is defined within the `<x-splade-script>` tag. This function is then called when the checkbox changes. The function alerts the value of `form.allocateme`, which is bound to the checkbox with `v-model`.